# Background image in a python plot

Tags: python, image, plot, background

I need to plot over an image. I use this code to display the image:

```
plt.figure()
mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
fname = 'erausal-valence.jpg'
image = Image.open(fname).convert("L")
arr = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(arr)
```

Over on this image I need to plot an array build with components:

```
for i in range(0, len(BPM)):    
    for k in range(0, len(BPM)):
        (X[k], Y[k]) = pol2cart(BPM[k], -SC[k]);
        plt.plot(X[k], Y[k])
```

but plot shows the image and doesn't show the plot of the X and Y arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of X and Y? I've used the code below and could plot a graph over an image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

imageFile = cbook.get_sample_data('ada.png')
image = plt.imread(imageFile)

plt.imshow(image)

coords = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600] 

plt.plot(coords, coords, 'r--', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the background image, you have to add this import :

```
from matplotlib import cbook
```

And now to fill it in the background you should add these lines before the show instruction:

```
imageFile = cbook.get_sample_data('<Path_to_your_image>')
image = plt.imread(imageFile)
plt.imshow(image)
```